# How could I Mock this code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I want to start mocking some code but I am unsure how to do it. I have read a few tutorials but I cannot apply it to my code (There maybe a reason behind it).
I am using NUnit and Moq.
(I have removed all other methods so I can just show you one).

Api Interface:

```
public interface IApiRequest
{
    Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request);
}
```

Method I want to Mock:

```
public async Task<UpcomingMovies> GetUpcomingMovies(int page)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest
            {
                Resource = "movie/upcoming",
            };
            request.AddParameter("page", page.ToString());
            request.AddParameter("language", "en");

            var api = new ApiRequest();

            return await api.ExecuteAsync<UpcomingMovies>(request);
        }
```

I'm not sure how I can mock this.

Update:

Is this now a valid test?

```
 Mock<IApiRequest> mock = new Mock<IApiRequest>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync<UpcomingMovies>(It.IsAny<RestRequest>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult<UpcomingMovies>(new UpcomingMovies()));
```

Comment: You shouldn't new your api, as you can't mock this in a test. It is better to pass in the constructor so in your test you can pass in the mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mock the `ExecutAsync` method you can do it like this:

```
Mock<IApiRequest> mock = new Mock<IApiRequest>();
mock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync<UpcomingMovies>(It.IsAny<RestRequest>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<UpcomingMovies>(/** whatever movies **/));
```

if you want to mock for a particlur request, replace `It.IsAny<RestRequest>()` with a reference to your request.

To effectively test your class you need something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IApiRequest api)
    {
        this.api = api; 
    }    

    public async Task<UpcomingMovies> GetUpcomingMovies(int page)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Resource = "movie/upcoming",
        };
        request.AddParameter("page", page.ToString());
        request.AddParameter("language", "en");

        return await api.ExecuteAsync<UpcomingMovies>(request);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    var expectedMovies = new UpcomingMovies(); // or whatever movies you need

    Mock<IApiRequest> mock = new Mock<IApiRequest>();
mock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync<UpcomingMovies>(It.IsAny<RestRequest>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<UpcomingMovies>(expectedMovies));

    var myClass = new MyClass(mock.Object);
    var result = await myClass.GetUpcomingMovies(1);

    Assert.IsTrue(expectedMovies == result);    
}
```

Comment: It's a valid mocking, but then you need to call `GetUpcomingMovies` from your test method, which needs to be `async`

Comment: Ok, But how would I call that? If I call it, then the mock would not be doing anything?

Comment: I've added a sample test, hope it helps.

Comment: That is an excellent example. Thank you very much Ned, it's got me understanding how it works better!